# How to tell flutter where Visual Studio 2017 Community edition is installed?

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, flutter-desktop

Flutter does not find my Visual Studio 2017 Community edition:

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel master, v1.7.12-pre.40, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18922.1000], locale nl-BE)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
    Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
[√] Android Studio (version 3.3)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.35.1)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I read that flutter only checks the default studio location. So it's not surprising that my community edition is not found. However, flutter refuses to run due to this error:

```
PS C:\src\flutterapps\flutter-desktop-embedding\example> flutter run
Downloading Web SDK...                                              1,1s
Launching lib/main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
Unable to find suitable Visual Studio toolchain. Please run `flutter doctor` for more details.
```

Is there any way to tell flutter where Visual Studio is located? I'd expect that some environment variable could be used to this purpose.

Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

> I read that flutter only checks the default studio location.

This is no longer the case; it now uses the [`vswhere`](https://github.com/microsoft/vswhere) utility installed with Visual Studio 2017+. This is expected to be reliable, so there is no manual configuration option.

If you can still reproduce this issue with the last version of Flutter master, please [file a bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues) including details of your Visual Studio installation.

Comment: vswhere fails to detect my visual studio: I will file a separate issue for it.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1455569/vswhere-fails-to-detect-my-visual-studio-community-2017